# Unable to render the JSON Object on browser in React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, for-loop

I am trying to display a JSON object which is an array in React. I am able to write the React code for doing that. However, I am not able to see the output in my browser.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import data from '../articles';
export default class fetchData extends Component {
  showData = (inputValue) => {
    inputValue.forEach((temp) => {
      return (
        <h1> temp.article_id </h1>
      );
    });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <h1> {this.showData(data)} </h1>
    );
  }
}
```

JSON object: (located in `../articles`)

```
[
  {
    "article_id": "101",
    "org_id": "10001",
    "reported_by": "Srilakshmi",
    "reported_on": "11-16-2016",
    "author": "Sree",
    "language": "English",
    "src_url": "",
    "key_words": "CS, Programming",
    "status": "Draft",
    "channel_ids": "IOE1",
    "title": "CS 101 Lession",
    "description": "CS 101 First Lession",
    "file_on_disk": "",
    "publish_on": "",
    "Published_on": "",
    "contentArray": ""
  },
  {
    "article_id": "102",
    "org_id": "10001",
    "reported_by": "Srini",
    "reported_on": "11-16-2016",
    "author": "Srini",
    "language": "English",
    "src_url": "",
    "key_words": "CS, DB",
    "status": "Draft",
    "channel_ids": "IOE2",
    "title": "CS DB 101 Lession",
    "description": "CS DB 101 First Lession",
    "file_on_disk": "",
    "publish_on": "",
    "Published_on": "",
    "contentArray": ""
  }
]
```

Any help with getting the data to display would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 mistakes here...

**First:**
`<h1> temp.article_id </h1>` won't print article ID. Use curly braces to print actual value

```
<h1>{ temp.article_id }</h1>
```

**Second:**
`forEach` array method just loops array, it does not create new one from values returned in callback. Use `map` method instead.

```
inputValue.map((temp) => {
    return (
        <h1> temp.article_id </h1>
    );
});
```

**Third**:
you are not returning from `showData` method at all.
Edit your code to return newly created array of components (that array created using `map` method)

```
showData = (inputValue) => {
    return inputValue.map((temp) => {
        return (
            <h1>{ temp.article_id }</h1>
        );
    });
}
```

**Bonus:**
make it short using arrow functions

```
showData = (inputValue) =>
    inputValue.map(temp => <h1>{ temp.article_id }</h1>)
```